# Problem with creating notification on android 8.0 And above

Tags: android, notifications

i got problem with creating notification for android 8.0 And above
Is this code correct? Please take a look on channel creating.

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            String name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
            String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH; //Important for heads-up notification
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("0", name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            channel.setShowBadge(true);
            channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        res = getIntent().getStringExtra("Reminder");
        Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(ReminderfabActivity.this);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_assignment_late_black);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Alert!");
        mBuilder.setContentText(res);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setAutoCancel(false);
        notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @Sony The notification doesn't show. This code do nothing

Comment: @Sony I'm not sure but i think it Is 0 (I saw this code today so i'm little bit dissoriented

Answer (score 0):

You should use `NotificationCompat.Builder` instead of `Notification.Builder`

Change this line `Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(ReminderfabActivity.this);`

to

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ReminderfabActivity.this,"0");
```

and also change this line `PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`
 you should use one of the flags from `PendingIntent`, not from `intent`

Comment: When i changed the code i got error: mBuilder Is unknown entity and can you write me the second code you mean?

Comment: which one? `notificationCompat.builder` or setting flag to pending indent?

Comment: setting flag to intent

Comment: The flags depends on your needs, please see this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent) for more details

Comment: The documentation for FLAG_UPDATE_CURENT says, "Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent already exists, then keep it but replace its extra data with what is in this new Intent." use this if that is what you want, or try another one if it doesn't work